# Need HTTP (REST) request forwarder to multiple nodes

Tags: http, rest

Assume there are multiple server machines. All of them run

- **keepalived** to share one *virtual IP*,
- **nginx** as *load-balancer*,
- and a **REST service** that receives all traffic.

Some of the REST requests do change the state of the server it runs on.
In order to **actively synchronize** the new state to all other servers (or neighbors) I want to send an *update-request* (including the necessary data) to all servers.

Is there any piece of software out there free to use?
Because it could work with all sorts of HTTP requests or even TCP/IP, I thought maybe there is already something like it?